# How to clear response cache directory in retrofit after reaching the max size?

Tags: retrofit

I am using Retrofit for making http requests for a news related application. For enabling offline reading, I am using okhttp as a client. I am able to cache the responses and show the content even when the user has no internet connection.

But I want to keep the Cache directory size to maximum 10 mb. If the cache directory hits its maximum size, I need to start removing responses from the cache directory. I would prefer to remove the least recently used response. I was wondering if okHttp/Retrofit provides built in mechanism for clearing the cache once the threshold is reached. If not, how should I go about removing the contents of the cache Directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Okhttp underneath Retrofit uses LRU (Least Recently Used) caching for keeping cached responses under size threshold. This means that it removes the oldest used item from cache. Further details are available in the [source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/ea89504d57c8349db3537e86d940bf1f0c951e9c/okhttp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/cache/DiskLruCache.kt).